Characterizing Strict Convexity in $B^* $-Spaces over Complex Fields
Statement:
Let $ X $ be a $B^*$-space over the complex field $ \mathbb{C} $. We aim to prove that $ X $ is strictly convex(i.e.for any $ x, y \in X $ where $ x \neq y $ and $ \|x\|, \|y\| = 1 $, implies $ \| \frac{x+y}{2} \| < 1 $), if and only if for any $ x, y \in X $ with $ x \neq y $ and $ \|x\| = \|y\| = 1 $, there exists $ \lambda \in \mathbb{C} $ such that $\| \lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y \| < 1 $.
This problem simplifies in the real case by examining the possible values of $ \lambda $, but it becomes more intricate when considering the complex case. Any insights or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

What is a $B^*$-space?

@KeeperOfSecrets Normed Vector Space

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1989904/equivalence-of-the-definition-of-rotund-space

@EvangelopoulosFoivos These are essentially two distinct problems. In our case, we don't assume (0 < $\lambda$ < 1); it can be any complex number (although certain ranges may be impossible), which is what adds complexity to this problem.

One implication is clear. For the other, suppose that negation of the first statement is true, that is suppose there are $x \neq y$ with $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$ with $\|\frac{x+y}{2}\| = 1$. Find a functional $\varphi \in X^*$ with $\|\varphi\|=1$ and $\varphi(\frac{x+y}{2}) = 1$ (it exists by Hahn-Banach theorem). Set $A = \{z \in X: \varphi(z) = 1\}$.
We will show that for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ we have $\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y \in A$. First note that both $x$ and $y$ are elements of $A$ (apply strict convexity of $\mathbb{C}$ on $\varphi(x)$, $\varphi(y)$ and $\varphi(\frac{x+y}{2}) = \frac{\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)}{2}$). Now fix any $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. Then
$$\varphi(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y) = \lambda \varphi(x) + (1-\lambda)\varphi (y) = \lambda + 1 - \lambda = 1$$
and $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \in A$. Hence, the negation of the second statement is true as well and we are done.

Thank you for your answer. I solved it by myself using the same method, but I'm still curious if there's a more ‘elementary’ approach, given that this serves as an intermediate lemma in proving the uniqueness of the Hahn-Banach Theorem (Taylor-Foguel).
